# Doubts about moving limit under integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral, pointwise-convergence

We have to count following integral:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_A\frac{\ln(n+y^3)-\ln n}{\sin(x/n)}d\lambda_2
$$
where $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2_+:1<xy<4,1<y/x<4\}$

Now in order to find integrable bound of above function, it may be useful to substitute variables: $\phi(x,y)=(s,st)$ and $\det\phi=s$, so now we integrate over set $\{(s,t)\in\mathbb{R}^2_+:1<s^2t<4,1<t<4\}$

$$
\int_A\frac{\ln(n+y^3)-\ln n}{\sin(x/n)}d\lambda_2=\int_A\frac{\ln(\frac{n+y^3}{n})}{\sin(x/n)}d\lambda_2=\int\frac{\ln(1+(st)^3/n)s}{\sin(s/n)}dsdt
$$
and $$\frac{\ln(1+(st)^3/n)s}{\sin(s/n)}<\frac{\ln(1+(4s)^3/{n})s}{\sin(s/n)}<(4s)^3$$which is integrable over bounded area.

And now I can say $$\lim\int\frac{\ln(1+(st)^3/n)s}{\sin(s/n)}dsdt=\int(st)^3dsdt$$

I have doubts, because I could just force this move without substitution. I could take $$\int_A\frac{\ln(1+\frac{y^3}{n})}{\sin(x/n)}d\lambda_2=\int_A\frac{\ln(1+\frac{y^3}{n})}{\sin(x/n)}\frac{x/n}{y^3/n}\frac{y^3/n}{x/n}d\lambda_2\to\int_A(y^3/x) dxdy$$ which is obviously different result under above substitution.

Comment: $\mathbb R^+$ is usually taken to mean $(0, +\infty)$, so is that a typo or a different convention?

Comment: @rubik, let say that it is was typo.

Comment: The $ds\, dt$ integral is over a different region, yes?

Comment: @zhw, yes, over $\phi(A)$

Comment: Why do you think the results are different then?

Comment: Well, now when you asked that question I see, that in fact they are not. I just forgot about determinant...

Answer (score 0):

You can move the limit inside the integral as long as you can show that the inside function is being dominated by a integrable function $g$.

This is the result of the [Dominated convergence theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem)

Comment: The OP seems to be aware of this.